# Set an extension and make full file from base64 encode to able to use laravel file method in php

Tags: php, laravel, file

I had base64 encoded data.
Look my code, please. 
First of all, see my code.

```
    $data = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA..........";

    $image_array_1 = explode(";", $data);

    $image_array_2 = explode(",", $image_array_1[1]);

    $data = base64_decode($image_array_2[1]);

    $imageName = uniqid().time().".png";
```

I want to set an extension .png to complete my file so that I can count this file extension by laravel method **$image->getClientOriginalExtension()** and others laravel file methods.
sorry for miss spell of language.
Hope I make you understand.

Comment: IMHO `$data = base64_decode(explode(';base64,', $data, 2)[1]);` it's less code. Let me understand: do you want to create an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` from raw data?

Comment: yea sir. I want to create an instance of **UploadedFile** from raw data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, although I cannot say if it's the best way to go about it. It's a full working example with a 1x1 black pixel png image. This assumes you already removed the `data:image/png;base64,` portion from the image data.

```
$data = base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR
    42mNk+A8AAQUBAScY42YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');

// Create a temp file and write the decoded image.
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $data);

// Get the path of the temp file.
$tempPath = stream_get_meta_data($temp)['uri'];

// Initialize the UploadedFile.
$imageName = uniqid().time().".png";
$file = new \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile($tempPath, $imageName, null, null, true);

// Test if the UploadedFile works normally.
echo $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // Shows 'png'

$file->storeAs('images', 'test.png'); // Creates image in '\storage\app\images'.

// Delete the temp file.
fclose($temp);
```