# Uploading image issue

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload the image directly to dropbox, and I use croppie too, so
my laravel upload code is:

```
    $user = User::find($request->id_user);

    $image = $request->image;

    list($type, $image) = explode(';', $image);
    list(, $image)      = explode(',', $image);
    $image = base64_decode($image);
    $image_name = $user->rut.'_'.'photo'.'_'. date("d_m_Y") .'.jpg';
    $path = public_path('temp_images/'.$image_name);

    Storage::disk('dropbox')->putFileAs(
        '/intranet_jisparking_pictures/', 
        $image,
        'image.jpg' 
    );
```

The problem is that it displays Call to a member function getRealPath() on string

how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Obviously you're passing a string to something that expects some kind of file object. Check the documentation for the functions you're using, and you should see where you're passing the wrong parameter type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the header for the `putFileAs` method in the `Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter` class:

```
/**
 * Store the uploaded file on the disk with a given name.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\File|\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile  $file
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return string|false
 */
public function putFileAs($path, $file, $name, $options = [])
```

It looks like the second argument is supposed to be a `File` or `UploadedFile`, but you are giving it the result of [base64_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) which is a string.

One way to solve this is by creating an instance of `UploadedFile` yourself in a temporary file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57635756/2509042) for an example.